# Pycharm : Fixing an unused function to used function

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I was wondering if you had any tips or help me understand why does Pycharm makes my function "unused" even though I need to call it later on in my code?

It is a local function within a class however, I am not sure how to debug it. There is no Error or any warning message.

Any tips, resources would help me out figure it out.

Thank you!!

Comment: Please note that disabled inspection does not highlight cases when a variable is actually not used, what is your case? It is possible to suppress the specific place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the Pycharm settings for `Unused local` in the `Inspections`:

```
PyCharm -> Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections -> Python -> Unused local
```

Here, you can uncheck the box to disable the warning or there are several options that allow you to customize as well as to change the `Severity level` ranging from `Error`, `Warning`, `Weak Warning` to `Server Problem` and `Typo`. See the screenshot below for further details.

[image]